# Implementing hypercolumn in neural nets with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I was trying to add [hypercolumns](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~rbg/papers/cvpr15/hypercolumn.pdf) idea to my neural net model. How can I do this using tensorflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a basic example.

Define the layer1,layer2,layer3 etc. then concat them below and now you have your hyper column.

```
conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(image, weights, [1, 1, 1, 1], 'SAME')
layer1 = tf.image.resize_bilinear(conv1, (224, 224))
...
layer2 = tf.image.resize_bilinear(conv2, (224, 224))
...
layer3 = tf.image.resize_bilinear(conv3, (224, 224))
return(tf.concat(0, [layer1, layer2,layer3]))
```

Comment: thanks @Steven! Also, Is there any way I can execute normal convolution and keep the hyper columns for the pixels/values for the final layer of convolution? For example, if input was 244x244 and final output of convolution was 7x7, then just keep equally spaced out 7x7 values from each previous layer and then concatenate them?

Comment: I probably need you to be a little more specific about what you'd like to get done. 
So the idea of hyper columns is more general than the input image size or even the size of the columns.
For example:
Suppose input size is as you say 244x244x3 (3 color channels)
First layer becomes half so 122x122x16
Next (and final) layer is 7x7x65.
Now the easiest thing to do is to do tf.image.resize_bilinear(layer1, (224, 224)) and same for layer two but that doesn't need to be the case.  You could also linearize both of the layers and concat them that way (however that loses spatial information).

Comment: You could also take a look at unpooling in tensorflow (it sounds like what you wanted) albeit it's still being developed at the moment. You can watch it here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2169

Comment: Thank you for the direction. I don't want precise(pixel level) segmentation as the hypercolumn papers does. I was trying to see instead of keeping hypercolumns for each pixel at input layer, what if we keep hypercolumns for each pixel at the last layer, what's the trade off between accuracy and speed if it's done this way, since the hypercolumn tensor for the size of input image is huge and takes relatively more computational time.

Comment: If you just keep the previous representation of layer n-1 and layer n then you do improve accuracy but at the cost of more computation and space.  The accuracy is hard to measure because that's task specific (so in some cases you might not improve at all you'd need to experiment).  The computation time is pretty easy to compute as you can just time how long a convolution takes with depth n and n+1, the space is also easy to compute as you can just multiply float (or double) * (size layer n + layer n+1).

Comment: Cool, thanks! So, the way from here would be to resize the earlier layers to the size of final layer (instead of resizing later layers to the size of initial ones) and then concatenate them to form the hyper column. Using this tensor, I can now make a segmentation prediction at NxN pixel level coarseness, where NxN is the size of all convolved outputs in the final layer, and the accuracy/space/time tradeoff can be evaluated by experimentions, right?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Going even further though you can resize any layer to arbitrary values. Say layer n-1 is mxm and layer n is pxp you can resize both to be of size kxL and concatenate them.  The only thing you'd need to do is know the ratio of k and L to the original dimension to know the coarseness.  The tradeoff between those 3 accuracy/space/time would need to be done experimentally.

Comment: oh yes, I can do that as well! Thanks again for your time and help :)